# How can an application access an OAuth service (such as Dropbox) on behalf of a user without having a server somewhere?

Tags: android, ios, server, oauth-2.0, client

What is the correct/recommended way to implement a Dropbox or a GoogleDrive or whatever client, as just a client and without a server, in terms of OAuth access?

A lot of providers (such as Dropbox) won't allow a redirect_uri that is not http/https. And on phones, it seems like google (and apple?) won't allow OAuth requests except from the OS's browser (for user convenience), meaning that the only way for the application to catch the authorization code (without a server involved) from oauth is to intercept a URI such as "http://localhost:9876/myapplication/" by telling the OS that it wishes to intercepts such a URI. Intercepting an http URI is not possible (the OS redirects it to the browser) without a complicated/involved setup which requires a server (something like [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)).

There is also the problem of having to tell the service provider about my application and retrieving a client id/secret, which I have to hardcode in the application.

There is an OAuth grant type in which I just take the user's username and password and directly send them to the server. This seems shady, and probably not well-received by users.

What is the correct way to do it? Do I need to have a server/service running to be able to create an application that is just a third party portal for those services?

Thanks,

Comment: This is an interesting situation. I've done something similar in the past by using a WebView. Although, have you tried the custom auth described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth)?

Comment: @gbazilio According to [this](https://auth0.com/blog/google-blocks-oauth-requests-from-embedded-browsers/) webviews can't be used to achieve a login through the service provider's OAuth portal (I already do that for PC and it works - I can control the webview and intercept the redirect URI). It is possible to do something similar to the article you linked but that requires asking the user directly for username and password through my own UI - which is not well-received by an application's user.

Comment: I got your point. You're right on that. By checking the link you sent, seems that only OAuth requests to Google Services are denied. Well, I was checking the code I used in the past to accomplish and a grant type of Authorization Code and I've used a WebView and it still working. I just tested it. There are weaknesses in the code that need to be improved, for sure, but it might be a starting point. One of the weakness, as you mentioned in your question, is the fact of hardcoding the Client ID and Client Secret.

Comment: So maybe for accessing Google services you can go other way than by manually implementing the flow your self and doing a WebView OAuth request since they have blocked it. Despite that, it seems WebView stills working for OAuth requests as I've just tested it with Github. But definitely there is a better approach than hardcoding both keys (cliend id and secret key) in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround (as suggested by @gbazilio's comment) is to just implement the authentication manually by calling the oauth endpoints inside a webview. To make it work with service providers such as google, which blocks oauth from webviews, is to set the user-agent header in the oauth requests to some mobile browser user-agent and everything will work just fine.

Comment: No. Changing the user-agent like you suggested smells a little bit to me and it doesn't sound like a real solution. By doing so you're actually trying to bypass a security/privacy measure Google has probably carefully taken and besides you're also taking this feature away from your user. Please, look further and there alternatives!